# Connect to multiple AWS RDS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have two AWS_RDS MySQL instances, i.e Instance1 and Instance2. Both are in the same region.

I am working on a script in RStudio (in Windows7) where I want to transfer data from Instance1 to Instance2.

I am connecting to the instances using git bash. But I am only able to connect to single instance at a time.

Is it possible to connect to multiple instances?

Edited:

Steps I followed:

1. First I connected to RDS using the following command in git bash:

   `ssh -N -L 9997:host:3306 -i key.pem user@ip`
2. Then from RStudio I connected to the instance using `dbConnect()` method.

Comment: Could you add the commands that you have tried using to accomplish this?

Comment: First I connect to the rds instance: ssh -N -L 9997:host:3306 -i key.pem user@ip      Then I connect to that instance from RStudio using dbConnect() method.

Comment: Okay I see. Could you edit your post and submit the complete script? That way we can follow each step and see what went wrong.